Suggest to get image filenames to my sink
I have a blob container containing image files. My goal is to extract the name of each image file and then place these names into a delimited file within the same blob container. For instance if the container contains three image files named 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jog
I aim to generate a delimited file, Filename.csv containing these three image file names.
Tried using getmeta data and foreach activities but unable to get the desired output.

I think we need a bit more details about what you have tried so far. Do you have any code examples, screenshots or workflows for what you have attempted? What output did you receive?
